# Spring create configuration bean depending on database table values

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, spring-bean

I have a few questions to accomplish what is required and I would appreciate your support.

To start with I have a configuration bean as shown below.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "level1.level2")
@Data
@Slf4j
public class Configuration{

    @NotEmpty
    private String valueA;
    @NotEmpty
    private String valueB;

    //Another logic methods
}
```

As you can see the values value1 and value2 were previously injected through the property files, but due to some changes these values will be obtained by the database.

Here is an example of the table's structure

| ID | Name | ValueA | ValueB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | conf1 | confA |
| 2 | otherValue | conf2 | confB |
| 3 | otherValue2 | conf1 | confC |

as you can see there can be multiple configurations, my initial idea is to be able to load all the initial configurations, and once I know which is the configuration I need (by means of a service request) get the corresponding information, create the bean and inject it in the subsequent beans (I don't know if it is possible yet).

so thank you very much if you can give me some recommendations on how to handle this scenario.

I tried with **BeanFactoryPostProcessor** but because this is for when I want to handle the beans once they are loaded but not instantiated, I still can't get the information from the database.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847730/how-can-i-build-a-database-based-spring-boot-environment-property-source) should be a good starting point - it's a few years old now, so some of the involved events/classes might have changed.

Comment: It sounds like what you really need is something like Spring Cloud Config, potentially with some auto-configuration classes.

Comment: @AndrewS Thanks I'm gonna look at it,

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- even though spring cloud could be useful, I would still have the same scenario since I have to load the configurations and depending on the input value choose and send it to spring.

Comment: Which is what auto-configuration is built for.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- but only with the configurations that are predefined and not those of the database (which can be created on demand), we have already validated these options and they do not fit the needs. thanks